# Нахождение общей скорости, если известна скорость по X и по Y

Tags: математика, любой-язык, геометрия

Как можно найти "общую" скорость, если известна скорость по X и по Y?

К примеру:

```
float speedx = mem.ReadFloat(add+0x44);
float speedy = mem.ReadFloat(add+0x48);

float normal_speedy = speedy*20;

float normal_speedx = speedx*20;

float current = (normal_speedx+normal_speedy)/2;
```

В переменной normal_speedy - мы узнаем скорость по Y.

В переменной normal_speedx - мы узнаем скорость по X.

Естественно, при отклонении от X'а - скорость будет меньше, или же вообще уходить в минус. Тоже самое и с Y'ком.

Нужно как-то найти общую скорость по этим двум координатам, которая не зависела бы от отклонения от X и Y. Как это сделать?

Comment: Теорема Пифагора в помощь - `Math.sqrt(normal_speedx * normal_speedx + normal_speedy * normal_speedy)`

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо дублировать собственные вопросы. Отформатируйте/удалите старый

Comment: Удалите старый вопрос, не нужно устраивать здесь свалку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По теореме Пифагора эта скорость будет равна квадратному корню из суммы квадратов скоростей.
Если код на java то это будет как то так
`float current_speed = Math.sqrt(speedx*speedx + speedy*speedy);`